# Lodash.uniqueId() is not generating unique ids. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

```
import { useState } from "react";
import lodash from "lodash";
function AddDrug(){
    const [dname, setDname] = useState("");
    const [dsummary, setDsummary] = useState("");
    const [dquantity, setDquantity] = useState(0);
    const [uuid, setUuid] = useState("0");

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            name: dname,
            summary: dsummary,
            quantity: dquantity,
            UUID: uuid
        }

        const r = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/drugs/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
            setUuid(lodash.uniqueId());
        })
    };

    const handleNameChange = (e) => {
        setDname(e);
    }

    const handleSummaryChange = (e) => {
        setDsummary(e);
    }

    const handleQuantityChange = (e) => {
        setDquantity(e);
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor={"name"}> Name:</label>
            <input type={"text"} id={"name"} name={"name"} value={dname} onChange={e => { handleNameChange(e.target.value) }} />
            <label htmlFor={"summary"} id={"summary"}>Summary:</label>
            <input type={"text"} id={"summary"} name={"summary"} value={dsummary} onChange={e => { handleSummaryChange(e.target.value) }} />
            <label htmlFor={"quantity"}>Quantity:</label>
            <input type={"number"} id={"quantity"} name={"quantity"} value={dquantity} onChange={e => { handleQuantityChange(e.target.value) }} />
            <button type={"submit"}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default AddDrug;
```

I am making an app that allows the user to create, update, and delete drugs in a pharmacy. The above code is from my functional component AddDrug.

Please help me fix this so a new unique UUID will be generated each time the form is submitted. Thanks

Comment: `window.location.reload()` destroys entire javascript and every variable in memory, why do you use it? `setUuid(lodash.uniqueId())` doesn't even happen because you reload in the previous line

Comment: @Konrad I use that so that the page reloads to show the addDrug form again. What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Just reset state values instead of reloading